# How to convert rows to columns in DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, pivot

I have a datagridview with

```
   CATEGORY         PROJECT    AMOUNT 
   ========         =======    ======
   Miscellaneous    project1     1200
   Miscellaneous    project2     4500
   Travel           project3     3000
   Miscellaneous    project4     2300
   Travel           project4     1000
```

I want to convert the above format to

```
       CATEGORY       project1   project2   project3    project4
       ========       ========   ========   ========    ========
       Miscellaneous   1200       4500         0         2300
       Travel           0           0         3000       1000
```

The project_name is dynamic, it can change

pls help.....

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: database is local database  .sdf file of AVALABLE IN .NET,sql compact edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server you can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to transform the rows of data into columns.

If you have a known number of values, then you can hard-code the query:

```
select category,
  coalesce(project1, 0) project1,
  coalesce(project2, 0) project2,
  coalesce(project3, 0) project3,
  coalesce(project4, 0) project4
from 
(
  select category, project, amount
  from yt
) d
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for project in (project1, project2, project3, project4)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61dbd/3).

But in your case it sounds like you will have an unknown number of values, as a result you will have to implement a dynamic SQL solution:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(PROJECT) 
                    from yt
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', Coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(PROJECT) +', 0) as '+ QUOTENAME(PROJECT)
                    from yt
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT category,' + @colsNull + ' 
            from 
            (
                select category, project, amount
                from yt
            ) d
            pivot 
            (
                sum(amount)
                for project in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61dbd/3). Both will give a result:

```
|      CATEGORY | PROJECT1 | PROJECT2 | PROJECT3 | PROJECT4 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| Miscellaneous |     1200 |     4500 |        0 |     2300 |
|        Travel |        0 |        0 |     3000 |     1000 |
```

Comment: can you help me with this one

Comment: can you help me with this one [convert rows to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127247/how-to-convert-row-to-columns-sql)

Answer (score 0):

use pivot query to fetch data from sql..and get result from sql as you want

Comment: I have used MAX and DECODE functions ,but it cant be effective for dynamic values in rows... please specify your suggestion