# How to convert row to columns?

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, sql-server-ce, pivot

I have the below table:

```
  PROCESS ID       VOUCHER DATE     CATEGORY_ID     PROJECT     AMOUNT
  -----------      ------------    ------------     -------     -------
  1001             12/03/13         Miscellaneous   pnr         1000
  1001             12/03/13         Miscellaneous   pjk         2000
  1002             20/07/13         Local Travel    pnr         3000
  1002             20/07/13         Local Travel    npk         3400
  1003             29/09/14         Miscellaneous   jpg         1000
  1004             23/10/13         Local Travel    pnr         2000
  1005             24/10/13         Miscellaneous   pnr         1000
  1005             24/10/13         Local Travel    pnr         1000
```

In the interface I will give **VOUCHER DATE** as between some date e.g., **20/01/13**  and **27/10/13** and I have to get the output as in the format below:

```
  CATEGORY_ID       pnr         npk         jpg
  -----------      -----       -----       -----      
  Miscellaneous    1000         0           1000
  Local Travel     6000         3400        0
```

The **PROJECT** is dynamic, it can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works in SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + PROJECT
                    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT FROM Table1 )sub
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM
                (
                SELECT CATEGORY_ID, PROJECT, AMOUNT 
                FROM Table1   
                --WHERE VOUCHER_DATE BETWEEN '' AND ''
                ) AS T1
                PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR PROJECT IN ('+@cols+')) AS T2

'
EXEC(@query)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54627/2/0)

Basically, you use dynamic SQL to set the list of projects since it can vary, then PIVOT as per usual, I commented out the voucher date criteria because the sample dates weren't in proper format. If some projects are excluded entirely by the date requirement, then you will also add the date criteria to the top portion that sets the project list.

Comment: how to do this with .sdf files using SqlCe connection,since they cannot have support stored procedures

Comment: I'm not familiar with the limitations of SQLCE, will look into it when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of values for project column are known and they are also few you can try this:

```
select category_id
    ,sum(case when project='pnr' then amount else 0. end) as pnr
    ,sum(case when project='npk' then amount else 0. end) as npk
    ,sum(case when project='jpg' then amount else 0. end) as jpg
from [yourtable]
where [voucher date] between @bd and @ed--@bd and @ed are the input interval
group by category_id
```

or to play with pivot command

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the project column values are unknown.so this is not possible